# Atribuição/Impressão valores a void * numa estrutura

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, cast

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct elem{

    void * d;

}Elem;

main(){

    Elem *p;
    Elem e;

    double pi = 3.14;

    e.d = &pi;
    p->d = &pi;

    printf("%f\n",p->d);
    printf("%f\n",e.d);


}
```

Quando faço os `printf`, os valores em `stdout` são completamente diferentes do valor que atribui ao ponteiro para `void`.

Como posso resolver isto?

Comment: Já consegue aceitar a resposta nesta aqui também? Após aceitar vai poder votar em tudo no site também, que é diferente de aceitar. Veja o [tour]

Comment: A resposta resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Realmente não é muito simples. O primeiro erro é que não inicializou o objeto apontando para `p`. A maneira usada normalmente não tem muita utilidade, mas entendo que seja um exercício. Tem que inicializar na [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), como eu fiz abaixo, ou no *heap*, como é mais útil.

Depois tem que fazer um *cast* quando for pegar o valor. Você provavelmente já sabe que esta é uma forma de armazenar qualquer valor, é uma forma de dar um dinamismo de tipos para a linguagem. Claro que isso tem um preço. O código fica inseguro. Precisa saber muito o que está fazendo para funcionar. Se usar as opções certas para compilar, o próprio compilador não deixa passar a forma errada. E isso é bom. Todo mundo deveria compilar códigos com todos os *warnings* ligados.

Ainda modifiquei para adotar o `main()` na forma padrão:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct elem {
    void * d;
} Elem;

int main() {
    Elem *p = &(struct elem) { .d = NULL }; //malloc(sizeof(Elem));
    Elem e;
    double pi = 3.14;
    e.d = &pi;
    p->d = &pi;
    printf("%f\n", *((double *)p->d));
    printf("%f\n", *((double *)e.d));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/RgBeIW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bcgsbuvb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/VoidPointerAtrib.c).

Comment: muito obrigado! realmente este é um exercício que fiz à parte, para tentar perceber o problema com Linked List ;)